# Pass variable from gitlab-ci.yml to Dockerfile without using docker build

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am new to docker.I want to pass gitlab-ci variable to Dockerfile. Tried lot of things but nothing works. Below is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
     api-tests:
  image: test-img
  stage: test
  services:
    - docker:abc
  variables:
    privileged: "true"
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
  script:
    - apk add dialog && apk add bind-tools
    - docker login -u $ci_account -p $ci_token $REGISTRY_HOST
    - git clone --single-branch --depth 1 --recurse-submodules --branch master ssh://git@git.easygroup.co:1234/test/code.git test && cd test
    - cd -
    - make test-project
    - TEST_PATH=first make test; r=$?
  after_script:
    - docker ps -a
    - docker logs --tail=50 test-project
```

Thanks

Comment: U can pass gitlab variables to dockerfile using docker build command, that will build the image, which you can use later, but as u mentioned in the title you dont want to use  build command, can u elaborate a bit why will you want to pass variables to dockerfile without rebuilding the image?

Comment: Its a prebuild code and i have to update something in this. they are using some make utility of linux  like "make test-project"

Comment: can you share makefile, they are using docker build command in there, you can pass env variables to makefile as well but for that u need to modify dockerfile for fetching arg from makefile

Answer (score 0):

You need to create environment variables using .gitlab-ci.yml variables sections. Once environment variables are created then can be accessed by script or other process.

Git lab docs:

```
Creating a custom environment variable
Assume you have something you want to repeat through your scripts in GitLab CI/CD’s configuration file. To keep this example simple, let’s say you want to output HELLO WORLD for a TEST variable.

You can either set the variable directly in the .gitlab-ci.yml file or through the UI.

Via .gitlab-ci.yml
To create a new custom env_var variable via .gitlab-ci.yml, define their variable/value pair under variables:

variables:
  TEST: "HELLO WORLD"

For a deeper look into them, see .gitlab-ci.yml defined variables.
```

More info here->https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#gitlab-ciyml-defined-variables

Comment: Thanks for your response . I have already tried this. But i am unable to read these variables under docker file

Comment: can you share how you are doing this in docker file.

Comment: "ARG FRONTEND_BUILD"   
"ENV FRONT_END_BUILD=${FRONTEND_BUILD}"
"echo "front_end" $FRONT_END_BUILD"

But its blank Even I tried echo $FRONTEND_BUILD